# Ammaps legend only appears on window resize

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using ammaps to create a map and trying to create a legend. I'm running in to a weird problem where the legend doesn't appear on initial load but only appears on window resize. Regardless of the window size, on any resize, the legend becomes visible (VERY WEIRD RIGHT?).

Code:

```
var icon = "M9.875,0.625C4.697,0.625,0.5,4.822,0.5,10s4.197,9.375,9.375,9.375S19.25,15.178,19.25,10S15.053,0.625,9.875,0.625";
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv", {
    /**
    * this tells amCharts it's a map
    */
    "type": "map",

    /**
    * create data provider object

    */
    "dataProvider": {
      "mapURL": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ggwc82/amcharts/master/unitedKingdomLow.svg",
      "getAreasFromMap": false,

      "images": [ {
        "latitude": 51.5074,
        "longitude": 0.1278,
        "svgPath": icon,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "label": "Dagenham Factory",
        "labelBackgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "labelColor": "#696D6E",
        "labelFontSize": 14,
        "labelShiftY": 00,
        "color": "#D30000",
        "title": "1 Warning",
        "url": "http://www.google.co.uk",
        "description": "DRM with id 09 is offline"
      },
      {
        "latitude": 53.4808,
        "longitude": -2.2426,
        "svgPath": icon,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "label": "Manchester Factory",
        "labelBackgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "labelColor": "#696D6E",
        "labelFontSize": 14,
        "labelShiftY": 0,
        "color": "#40D300",
        "title": "No Issues",
        "url": "http://www.google.co.uk",
        "description": ""
      },
      {
        "latitude": 54.9783,
        "longitude": -1.6178,
        "svgPath": icon,
        "scale": 0.7,
        "label": "Newcastle Factory",
        "labelBackgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "labelColor": "#696D6E",
        "labelFontSize": 14,
        "labelShiftY": 0,
        "color": "#D3D000",
        "title": "2 Alerts",
        "url": "http://www.google.co.uk",
        "description": "DRM with id 23 is inactive. DRM with id 25 is inactive."
      }
    ],

  },


  /**
  * create areas settings
  * autoZoom set to true means that the map will zoom-in when clicked on the area
  * selectedColor indicates color of the clicked area.
  */
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true,
    "unlistedAreasColor": "#C8E1D6",
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"

  },
  "zoomControl": {
    "zoomControlEnabled": false,
    "homeButtonEnabled": true,
    },
  "dragMap": false,
  "showDescriptionOnHover": true,
  "allLabels": [
        {
        "text": "Default Factory View - UK Sites",
        "bold": true,
        "size": 20,
        "color": "#696D6E",
        "align": "center",
        "y": 100
        }
    ],

} );


var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
console.log("hello");
map.addLegend(legend,"legenddiv");
legend.data = [{title:"first", color:"#CC0000", markerType: "circle"}, 
               {title:"second", color:"#00CC00", markerType: "circle"},
              {title:"second", color:"#ffff00", markerType: "circle"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `makeChart` function. This function is an helper which allow you to create in a single call a chart / map, configure it using JSON, display it in the container div passed as first argument and get back the instance previously created.

You're adding the legend to your instance but it's already rendered by the `makeChart` helper when you're hitting your code adding the legend. So, when adding the legend to an already rendered chart, it'll only be visible when re-rendered which happens when you resize your window.

As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap), the `AmMap` class can not be instantiated explicitly so the use of the `makeChart` method is mandatory but you can also configure your legend in the JSON config instead of doing it later.

```
/**
 * Legend
 */
"legend": {
  "width": 400,
  "backgroundAlpha": 1,
  "backgroundColor": "#fff",
  "borderColor": "#000",
  "borderAlpha": 1,
  "bottom": 15,
  "right": 15,
  "horizontalGap": 10,
  "data": [{
    "title": "first",
    "color": "#CC0000",
    "markerType": "circle"
  }, {
    "title": "second",
    "color": "#00CC00",
    "markerType": "circle"
  }, {
    "title": "third",
    "color": "#ffff00",
    "markerType": "circle"
  }]
},
```

I've put a [little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74z7teox/) based on your question including a legend configured in JSON. The legend is displayed at the same time of the map, no resize or anything required to show it.